# Subset based on row condition

Tags: r

I read lot of articles, but can't seem to find an answer for this

```
census <- read.csv("data.csv", header=FALSE)
count <- 0
for(i in 1 : nrow(census)) {
  if(!(census[i,2] == '?' || census[i,7] == '?' || census[i,14] == '?')) {
    # need these values to be in the data frame.
    count <- count + 1
  }
}
```

There are a few columns which have unknown values represented by `?`. How can I get a subset of the census data frame without the `?`

Comment: If you have strings ("?") mixed in the numeric values, this will force the data type to factor/character which might not be desirable. If it's appropriate to treat these values as missing (NA), try setting `read.csv(..., na.strings="?")` to automatically convert to NA and preserve the proper type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know:
Even if one row has `"?"`, that row will be removed

```
census[(apply(census =="?", 1, sum)==0), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is another trial. `?` is replaced with NA then `complete.cases()` is used for subsetting.

```
set.seed(1237)
census <- data.frame(col1 = sample(c('a','?','b'), 10, TRUE),
                     col2 = sample(c('a','?','b', 'c'), 10, TRUE),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
census[] <- lapply(census, function(x) { x[x == '?'] <- NA; x} )
census[complete.cases(census),]
   col1 col2
1     a    a
2     b    c
3     a    a
5     a    b
6     b    a
7     b    c
10    b    a
```